# How to detect a newline with space

Tags: php, html

my string is "mom dad" (also saves the same attribute in table db).

After I query and print to the table, I want to separate a newline with a space. The output should be mom+newline+dad, but it prints "mom dad" without a new line.

Comment: echo '<td>' . $row['meaning'] . '</td>';
CODE PRINT

Comment: *"here is my code"*: ehm...

Comment: "*..but it also mom dad.*" WHAT ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar he is trying to say but it also prints "mom dad"

Answer (score 4):

Use PHP **explode()** function like this :

```
<?php
    $input = "mom dad";
    $inputArray = explode(" ", $input);
    //now inputArray is like this ["mom", "dad", ...]
    echo $inputArray[0]."<br>".$inputArray[1];
?>
```

Hope it helps
Thanks

Comment: explode would be the easiest method. You beat me to answering this question lol

Comment: Haha! just trying to help here :p

Comment: am try to echo '<td>';
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($meaningarray); $i++) {
  echo $meaningarray[$i] . "<br>";

 }
 echo '</td>';

but it also print in same line

Comment: try echo for ($i = 0; $i < count($meaningarray); $i++) { echo "<tr><td>".$meaningarray[$i]."</td></tr>"; }

Comment: http://s32.postimg.org/c9wwdi58l/Untitled.png

Comment: u can see that pic on line3 it not seperate newline i loop for print by array form explode

Comment: Use echo "<td><div>".$meaningarray[$i]."</div></td>";

Comment: not work it also slide to rate colum

Comment: http://s32.postimg.org/va132eqyt/Untitled.png

Comment: hey i think explode not seperate by space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110287/discussion-between-non-brazilian-and-vaibhav-jain).

Comment: Nopes, explode supports space